# Cassandra Cluster using Docker Swarm - Access from outside

Tags: docker, proxy, cassandra, load-balancing, docker-swarm

I have a cassandra cluster/service running using docker swarm mode and using overlay network. I have a need for my applications to access the cassandra database from outside of the overlay network. The applications should be able to access any of the cassandra node directly. Is there any solutions which helps achieving this?

I tried my hand on [docker-flow-proxy](https://github.com/vfarcic/docker-flow-proxy) but am not able achive the objective. Here is what I tried.

Created the cassandra cluster...

```
sudo docker service create -e CASSANDRA_SEEDS=192.168.0.3 --detach=false --network overlay-net --network proxy --replicas 5  --name cassclu bitnami/cassandra
```

Started docker-flow-proxy container...

```
sudo docker service create --name proxy --detach=false -p 80:80     -p 443:443  -p 9042:9042 -p 9160:9160   -p 8080:8080     --network proxy     -e MODE=swarm     vfarcic/docker-flow-proxy
```

Configured the proxy....

```
sudo curl "192.168.1.76:8080/v1/docker-flow-proxy/reconfigure?reqMode=tcp&serviceName=cassclu&servicePath.1=/&port.1=9042&srcPort.1=9042&&servicePath.2=/&port.2=9160&srcPort.2=9160"
```

But when I try to test accessing from teh host machine using cqlsh I get the following error

```
cqlsh -u cassandra
Password:
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

**UPDATE:** Found that the issue was happening as the cassandra node was out of the cassandra cluster while the docker container was up.

Is there a way with which we can make docker swarm aware of the cassandra status so that the requests are not routed to the cassandra node which is down?

Comment: Swarm ingress routing mesh be used to expose the swarm service to all nodes in the swarm network and external applications can access it. Would that help your usecase?

Comment: It opens the port for external access through ingress routing mesh, but somehow it does not work for Cassandra cluster. Not able to root cause this.

Comment: @Sreeni Here is the test. #sudo docker service inspect --format="{{json .Endpoint.Spec.Ports}}" cassclu
[{"Protocol":"tcp","TargetPort":9042,"PublishedPort":9042,"PublishMode":"ingress"},{"Protocol":"tcp","TargetPort":9160,"PublishedPort":9160,"PublishMode":"ingress"}]


#sudo cqlsh  -u cassandra
Password:
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})

Comment: Can you pls check "docker service ls" and "docker service logs" to see if any error. Wondering if u r hitting this issue(https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/27157)

Comment: @Sreeni Thanks. I found the issue which was because one of the cassandra node was down because of some ip/hostname conflict issue which swarm mode is not aware of I guess as the container was still up and running. Is there a way to make docker swarm aware of cassandra node status so that the requests are not routed to this node.

Comment: You can define your own health check(https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#healthcheck) and Swarm will take care of routing to only healthy containers.